# TypeMock Isolator Complete compatibility with Isolator Basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, typemock, typemock-isolator

I'm a new to unit testing and also to Typemock. I wanna choose typemock, cuz I have a lot of legacy code with a lot of dependencies. 
I know that `Isolator Basic` is a free version, but they are also give a 30 days trial version of `Isolator Complete`. So I got a trial version just to try. But before I start to write unit tests, I have a question - If I make tests with `Isolator Complete`, can I run them on another PC with `Isolator Basic`, or at least build project without falling down another tests(which contains `Isolator Basic` features)?

Does this compatibility possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.

Probably it will not work. With Isolator basic license you can only fake interfaces and abstract classes so if you are using Isolator complete license to fake concrete types and than you'll try to run the tests with basic license the test will fail.
The build however will not fail. You will get the exception on runtime.

Comment: You're very sure that the basic license doesn't allow you to mock concrete or sealed classes?  I'm able to instantiate a mock of ExchangeService in my tests, and I'm using the basic license.